how to make strings dont overlap when enter is pressed Python
i made a function that refresh a string to show the time left of a code:
try:
    totp = pyotp.TOTP('{}'.format(key_id))
    if t:
       print(end="\n\n")
       while True:
          time_remaining = int(totp.interval - datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() % totp.interval)
          multi_line = 'Code: {}\nTime left: {} \n'.format(totp.now(), time_remaining)
          magic_char = '\033[F'
          ret_depth = magic_char * multi_line.count('\n')
          print('{}{}'.format(ret_depth, multi_line), end='')
          sleep(1)
except Exception as e:
    print("Unexpected error: {}".format(e))

but when i press enter(intro or whatever its called) the text goes down and overlaps with the line above
i have a similar function thats refresh a table and happens the same:

heres the code of this one:
def get_table(header):
    data = json.load(open(JSON_PATH))
    key_list = []
    for i in data:
        totp = pyotp.TOTP("{}".format(data[i]["key"]))
        time_remaining = int(totp.interval - datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() % totp.interval)
        key_list.append([i, data[i]["name"], data[i]["issuer_name"], totp.now(), time_remaining])
    table = tabulate(key_list,headers=header, tablefmt="fancy_grid")
    return table


if t:
   magic_char = '\033[F'
   table = "{}\n".format(get_table(["ID", "Name", "Issuer", "Code", "Time Remaining"]))
   print("\n" * table.count("\n"), end="")
   while True:
       table = "{}\n".format(get_table(["ID", "Name", "Issuer", "Code", "Time Remaining"]))
       ret_depth = magic_char * table.count('\n')
       rint('{}{}'.format(ret_depth, table), end='')
       sleep(1)
else:
   print(table)

i tried using python curses but i seen a post  that says it cant be done without clearing the screen, also i tried using the \r at the begging of a string but it doesnt work

Do I get your question right: if you type on your keyboard while your code is printing something, that will distort your output? That's basically how terminals work is they are set to echo the input.
